# Spring Integration Channels on Content

Tags: java, spring, integration, spring-integration

I have used Spring Integration in my current successfully for some of the needs. Awesome..

There is some weird behavior observed on a heavy load  where-in the same message seems to be processed more than once. I can confirm that because there are multiple rows in the database which is typically the last command on the chain that is configured over the channel.

Digging into the manual further, it looks seems like load-balancing is done automatically by spring. The manual says that the message is balanced between multiple message handlers.

Question is:

1. How many handlers are present on a channel by default? The spring XML that gets loaded does not seem to have that configuration. All i do is this (per the recommendation in the manual):

> ```
> <int:channel id="SwPath.Channel"/>
> <int:chain id="SwPath.chain" input-channel="SwPath.Channel">
> </int:chain>
> ```

I can disable the fail-over but I am curious to know how many are present by default.

Comment: <int:channel id="SwRequest.Channel"/>

<int:chain id="SwRequest.chain input-channel="SwRequest.Channel">
</int:chain

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked on those load balancers, but I remember that the default number of threads in the thread pool was somewhere between 2 and 10.

It is possible that you have found a concurrency bug.

If you turn on TRACE logging the load balancer will give you a lot of information, but that could easily hide the problem.

If you would create a JIRA issue with a JUnit test case, I'm sure it would be much easier to figure out what happens exactly.